# Changing web.config of a web application of website

Tags: asp.net, server, application-pool

My website is configured with 3-4 web applications. I deploy them individually when required. Website and web applications share the same application pool. I want to recycle the application pool when I deploy any of the web application. So, if I change the web.config of 1 of the web application than will it recycle the application pool. If not than how can I achieve the same.

```
Website
  |_ Web Application 1
  |_ Web Application 2
  |_ Web Application 3
```

Answer (score 1):

As per this article http://blogs.msdn.com/tess/archive/2006/08/02/asp-net-case-study-lost-session-variables-and-appdomain-recycles.aspx there are few actions which cause the app pool to recycle. Web.config changes is one of them. Other options are to replace the dll of your web app.

Just curious why you have all three web apps running under same app pool because one web app deployment will affect other apps. Also, app pool crash due to error in one web app will cause other apps to stop.